# Backup of MySQL fails on cPanel server

Tags: backup

I have big problem on my cPanel server.
When I do daily and weekly backup or my client do a Full Backup from cPanel, after dumping databases and messages "OK"
we get error:

*ERROR: Failed to dump one or more databases
...Done*

And when I try to restore backup, databases are size 0 KB!

This is my.cnf file:

```
[client]
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
port=3306
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M
quick
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
open_files_limit=41360
[myisamchk]
write_buffer=2M
key_buffer_size=128M
read_buffer=2M
sort_buffer_size=128M
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
[mysqld]
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
max_allowed_packet=1M
key_buffer_size=256M
max_connections=200
max_heap_table_size=32M
tmp_table_size=32M
thread_concurrency=8
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
table_open_cache=9000
table_definition_cache=9000
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
port=3306
binlog_format=mixed
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=8M
query_cache_size=64M
skip-external-locking
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
local-infile=0
log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M.
```

I did *mysql_upgrade --force*, restarted MySQL, *mysqlcheck -r -A* ...
This error is showing for every backup of every user account databases

I found this now:

Determining mysql dbs......mysql version: 5.5...mysqldump: unknown variable 'default-storage-engine=MyISAM'
...mysqldump version: ...
Local mysql tools are version 4.x and remote mysql is 5.x. Unable to backup stored procedures.

Should I remove line *default-storage-engine=MyISAM* ?
Or change it to *default-storage-engine=MYISAM* ?
Thanks for help

Edit: 
I added just this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
```

And successfully maked backup with no errors, so problem is in my.cnf file, but what line is making crap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move line **open_files_limit=41360** from 

**[mysqldump]** section

 
to 

**[mysqld]** section

That is causing the problem

Comment: Thank you!                                    
It's fixed now.                                           
What this variable was for?
I got it from my-huge.cnf

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit